# Change only rgb values of image and convert back to image

Tags: java, image, raster

I need to convert my image `.bmp or .jpg` to `byte[]`, change some values `rgb`, convert it back to image and see a difference - some wrong pixels on my image.

**I tried doing it just by converting image to `byte[]` changing it and converting back, but by changing random values I get a corrupted image**.

So ,how do I access only the changeable values of my image?

Started with this but not sure where to do next:

```
    File file = new File("image.jpg");
    BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(file);
    WritableRaster raster = bufferedImage.getRaster();
    DataBufferByte data = (DataBufferByte) raster.getDataBuffer();

   byte[] pixels = data.getData();
```

Would appreciate any help.

Comment: BufferedImage has two getRGB methods, where you can modify the int results and put the int back into the image with the setRGB method.  The [BufferedImage Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html) describes all the methods available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution. To convert regb values of .bmp image  to binary vector that I need to change I applied this solution:

```
public String imageToVector(BufferedImage image) throws Exception {
        String vectorInString = "";
        for (int x = 0; x < image.getWidth(); x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < image.getHeight(); y++) {
                Color color = new Color(image.getRGB(x, y), false);
            vectorInString = vectorInString.concat(decimalToBinary(color.getRed()));
            vectorInString = vectorInString.concat(decimalToBinary(color.getGreen())); 
            vectorInString = vectorInString.concat(decimalToBinary(color.getBlue())); 
            }
        }
        return vectorInString;
}
```